# Create ubercart Pre Order drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I am looking for a solution to create a pre-order function using ubercart 3 and Drupal 7

Basically I am creating a website whereby only registered retail customers can place orders online using the website but I want to add products to the site that have not arrived yet and have the add to order button display as pre-order and show an ETA of when the product is arriving.

Anyone have an Idea how I can achieve this ?

Comment: What does "ETA" mean?

Comment: Estimated Time Of Arrival

Answer (score 0):

The Estimated Time Of Arrival can be a **simple product date field** that you will set.

Also, since you want the product to be available for preorder you can alter the button label using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). And the if statement for the button (so that you alter only the products that have a preorder) will be the **ETA field above** or an extra helper **field of boolean type** that will enable the "Preorder" state.

Comment: @Sfitzg Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).